# How do you make flash access hyperlinks for knowing where the user wanted to navigate?

Tags: flash, navigation

In this web-app, when you supply this link: http://listen.grooveshark.com/#/playlist/Mellow_Magic/15982097, it navigates directly to that playlist. 
How do you do that in flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use what's called "deep linking". Basically, you ask Flash to look at the URL, then use the content after the hash (#) to modify the state of your Flash application.

I believe the "canonical" implementation is SWFAddress: http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GrooveShark automatically calls that link, then goes through the list and adds it to the user interface. You would have to do the same, manually, in Flash.